# Mathematical Fundamentals of Physical Simulation

Tags: dynamical-systems, simulation

Simulation in general refers to all sorts of modelling done on computers, but what I'm looking for is general mathematical body of theory for doing simulation. That is, theories that explain e.g. how time is handled in functions representing physical phenomena.

Is this in the domain of [Dynamical Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system) perhaps?

Any good resources?

Comment: I don't think you're going to find any nice comprehensive resource here. Narrow your scope a bit and people can help a lot more.

Comment: @Ian What I'm trying to spot is the names of the mathematical subfields that these belong into. So I can look for resource by the names.

Comment: Numerical analysis; PDE; ODE; probability; certain aspects of topology and geometry (e.g. manifolds); dynamical systems.